# Reuse database session for several queries?

Tags: java, database, scala, playframework, slick

I am thinking of which of the following approaches that is the better.
To reuse a session for a larger scope or use smaller scopes?

Two examples follows to illustrate the differences.

Example 1 small scopes:

```
  def thumbnail(id: Int) = SecuredAction { implicit request =>
    DB.withSession { implicit session => Models.get(id) } match {
      case None => NotFound("The requested model is either not in the db or you lack access to it.")
      case Some(model) => {
        Ok(views.html.model.thumbnail(model, DB.withSession { implicit session => Tags.tags(model) }))
      }
    }
  }
```

Example 2 large scope:

```
def thumbnail(id: Int) = SecuredAction { implicit request =>
    DB.withSession { implicit session =>
      Models.get(id) match {
        case None => NotFound("The requested model is either not in the db or you lack access to it.")
        case Some(model) => {
          Ok(views.html.model.thumbnail(model, Tags.tags(model)))
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I would (and usually do) use the second approach, I don't actually know how heavy is for Slick to open a new session (and in general for databases) but why would renounce to a simple performance improvement?

From a workflow point of view it doesn't make sense to just open a session, use it for a small operation, close it and then immediately after open another one, the only thing which comes to mind is that you could have a very intensive database operation and the session may not last enough (depending on your DBMS), probably only then it makes sense to use a new one.

Also note that the first approach is much less readable than the second and I would start wondering why who implemented the first approach did it in that way.

Anyway just my 2 cents, I would have posted it as a comment but it's too long.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you clarify what this means? "I would start wondering why who implemented the second approach did it in that way."
If I understand the sentence correctly then I implemented both approaches myself.

Comment: Sorry, I meant as an external reading your code I would be brought to think that you had session problems (like expiring session) and that the `get` operation is very intensive, I was just thinking as somebody else reading your code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, now I get what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The second avoids any duplication, so I'd vote for the second.

You tried to make your code easier to read with the first solution, but actually, it is harder to analyse.

Indeed, it's not often that we see this pattern in scala:

```
{...} match { ...  //brackets just before matching
```